# Oops I need runlevel 1

Tags: boot, init.d

So I have a bug in a script in my init.d directory and bottom line...I can't completely boot the pi.

How can I boot into runlevel 1 (single user mode) so I can fix the bug?

Comment: Check this link for several options http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=16185

Comment: If you want to access and change SD card Linux partition files from Windows you can do it with **[one of these utilities](http://www.howtoforge.com/access-linux-partitions-from-windows)**.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to force the pi to boot into runlevel 1 so I fired up a fedora live disk I had laying around and used the terminal to remove the script in question from the /etc/init.d directory

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's not exactly a way to enter runlevel 1, but there is "safe mode" boot option in raspberry Pi firmware. To enable it, you have to insert a jumper between pins 5 and 6 on P1 (GPIO) header when booting.

[image: Safemode pins]

If you do this, bootloader will ignore the `config.txt` file (except from `avoid_safe_mode` option which can be used to disable this feature) and will try to boot `kernel_emergency.img` (if available) instead of `kernel.img`.

Default `kernel_emergency.img` has special emergency `initramfs` build in and it will boot to this busybox based OS so that you can fix the problems in your OS manually (or change kernel boot parameters to run runlevel 1 at next boot). Remember to run `sync` before powering down since `reboot` or `shutdown` commands may not work.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

- Hit shift when starting up.
- Hit "e" to edit config
- tab over to cmdline.txt
- add to the end of the line

  `init=/bin/sh`
- hit ok, then Esc to boot...... it will boot you in to a command line

  `# /etc/init.d/mountall.sh`
  (this will do something)

  `# mount -n -o remount,rw /`
  (this will remount / so you can make changes)
- now you should be able to edit the init.d config......
- when you reboot again.... hold shift and remove the init=/bin/sh

Comment: Excellent! I'd found instructions to init sh but was missing the remount stuff I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Several of the other answers here are now incorrect:

- The GPIO jumper pin method was [removed](http://elinux.org/RPI_safe_mode) from the upstream OS, so it only works now if you're using a NOOBS image
- Raspbian Jessie's move to systemd breaks the `init=/bin/sh` hack. When you do this, it complains, `can't access tty: job control turned off`

Fortunately, there is a solution that works, which actually gives real single-user access: add a space and a `1` at the end of `cmdline.txt`, right after the `rootwait` parameter.

The hold-Shift boot menu doesn't exist with the stock Raspbian Jessie OS image, so you'll have to do this by editing `/boot/cmdline.txt` from another computer if you aren't using the NOOBS image.

Comment: Hmmm, for what it's worth, this only half-way worked on the image I have.  It gave a thing for a "rescue mode", but that gave an error message saying it `Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.` -- did I miss a step?  Or did they just increase security at some point?  Or... ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot into runlevel 1

   ```
   $ sudo init 1
   ```
2. After booting into runlevel 1

   ```
   $ passwd
   ```

NOTE: to runlevel 1, change the file `/etc/inittab` from `id:2:initdefault:` to something similar like: `id:1:initdefault:`

Comment: Is that really _booting_ into runlevel 1, though? I mean, it can hardly be done if the machine isn't booted in the first place, can it?

Comment: No, it certainly is not. What it is, is changing run level on a running system.