# Change default username

Tags: setup

I want to change the default username (pi) to something, I tried

```
usermod -l newusername pi
```

but that gives me

```
usermod: user pi is currently used by process 2104
```

Is there another way to modify the root account or disable this and create a new root account?

Comment: Booting into safe mode (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3751/oops-i-need-runlevel-1) should make that possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ps -lp 2104` will give you some information about what the process is.  You can check that and `kill 2104`.

Note you'll have to do this *logged in as root*, or some other user with the permissions to do it.  It probably will not work via `sudo`, etc.

You'll also have to rename the home directory.

IMO you should just create a new user with whatever name, and leave pi there, but that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I just like to have a clean system and the unused user for some reason bothers me, but i'll just leave it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 17):

**If you're in the console** of the pi there is a way to get around this without having to make another user (or set a pw on root):

Assuming nothing else is running with your username other then the shell on the console - no X session, no ssh login, etc:

```
exec sudo -s
cd /
usermod -l newname -d /home/newname -m oldname
```

**The reason this works:**

- `sudo -s` tells `sudo` that instead of just running the command as another user, it should run a new shell as the given user
- `exec` tells the shell that instead of spawning off a new process when it runs a command (hence leaving the shell process running as the logged in user), that the shell should *overwrite* itself with the new process. This means that when the `exec` command ends the shell is gone. In the case of a login shell, that equates to disconnecting from the login.
- the `cd /` is optional. At a minimum, things get a bit confusing if you move a directory you're in (your login starts out sitting in the user `pi` home directory). Sometimes this will cause a fail, so it's better to be safe than sorry.

Therefore with `exec sudo -s` you're overwriting your shell with a new shell that has been created as a different user (the root user in this case).

P.S. be sure to give `usermod -d` a **full (hard link) path** or you'll end up moving the account's home to somewhere you don't expect and have a bogus directory entry in `passwd`.

Comment: mike's solution works fine for me...
thanks
and one more thing before doing this steps goto tty (ctrl + alt + f1).
and follow the steps given by mike.

Answer (score 5):

The answers above are correct, I just want to give another option that may suits you better.

### Assuming:

- A brand new raspberry pi
- You want to change the default username `pi` to `mypie`
- You want to adapt also the main group from `pi` to `mypie`
- You want other things to work out like sudo and auto-login

### Proceed to:

#### Step 1: stop user `pi` from running before the change.

- Boot it, go to RPI configurations and

  - allow SSH,
  - disallow auto-login
  - hit ok
- Press ALT+F1 to go to the first tty
- Escalate to root with `sudo su -`
- Edit `$vim /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service`

  - Find and *comment* (#) the line

    - `#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I $TERM`

    you can *uncomment* it later if you want console *autologin*, but then don't forget to change the user `pi` to your new username `mypi`
- Create a new root password with `passwd`. (DON'T FORGET IT)
- Type `reboot`

#### Step 2: make the user change

- If you see the graphical login prompt, you are good. Do **not** login. Instead, press ALT+F1 (* if you want to do it via ssh, see the apendix)
- After ALT+F1, you should see a `login` question (and not an autologin).
- Login as `root` with your root password. Now you are alone in the system, and changes to `pi` will not be met with `usermod: user pi is currently used by process 2104`. Check with `ps -u pi` to see an empty list.
- Very carefully, key by key, type `usermod -l mypie pi` . This will change your username, from `/etc/passwd` file, but things are not ready yet. Anyway, check with `tail /etc/passwd` and see the last line `mypie:1000:...` The 1000 is the UID and it is now yours.
- Try `su mypie` just to be sure. Do nothing. Just `exit` again to root. It should work. Now you need to adjust the group and a `$HOME` folder.

#### Step 3: make the group change

- Type, again carefully, `groupmod -n mypie pi` . This will change the `pi` group name. Check it with `tail /etc/group` and you will see the last line the new name associated with `GID` 1000.
- Just to clarify, type `ls -la /home/pi` and you will see that the `pi` HOME now belongs to you, `mypie`.

#### Step 4: lets adopt the new home.

- I see in the answers above the creation of a new folder, copying everything. No need. Lets just use the same.
- First move to `cd /home` to make it easier. Type `ls -la` and see `pi`, onwer `mypie` group `mypie`
- Type carefully: `mv pi mypie` . You now need to associate this change with your new user.
- Type carefully: `usermod -d /home/mypie mypie` . This will change your home directory. Check it with `tail /etc/passwd` and look at the sixth field (separated by `:`).

#### Step 5: some adjusts after the fact.

- Reboot with `reboot`
- Login as your new user `mypie` in the graphical interface.
- Open a terminal.

*Change your password*

- Type `passwd` to change the password of `mypie` to something else than `raspberry`
- Type `sudo su -` and you will be asked your password.

*auto-login again if you will (I don't recommend, but well)*

- If you want to autologin your new account, edit the file:

  - `$vim etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
  - find the line with `#autologin-user=`, change it to `autologin-user=mypie` (no *comment* #)
- If you want back the ALT+F1 autologin, find and edit the file:

  - `$vim /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service` and change the line
  - `#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin mypie --noclear %I $TERM`

*Make your sudo passwordless again (I don't recommend as well)*

- Move yourself (root) to `cd /etc/sudoers.d`
- Rename the file `010_pi-nopasswd` to `010_mypie_nopasswd`
- Open it `vim 010_mypie_nopasswd` and change the line `pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to, obviously `mypie ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. It is read-only, so save it forcing with `:x!`

*While you are into it, change your hostname*

- Edit `$vim /etc/hosts` and change `127.0.1.1   raspberry` to something more appropriate like `127.0.1.1    myoven`.
- Edit `$vim /etc/hostname` and let a single line with `myoven`.

*Done*

#### Step 6: reboot

- Type, carefully, `reboot`

---

#### Appendix - ssh

- You may want to do this via ssh. For this to work, first you need to allow root login.
- Find the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Comment the line `#PermitRootLogin without-password`
- Add the line `PermitRootLogin yes`
- Save, exit, restart ssh with `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

---

- After you have done it, undo this changes as they are too dangerous to let that way.
- Same file, delete `PermitRootLogin yes` line and remove the comment from `PermitRootLogin without-password`

---

**Note 1:** This is a guide, and the content deals with very dangerous commands. Backup first, or be aware that maybe you will need to burn again your image. As I am assuming a brand new raspberry pi, there is not much to backup anyway. But if you adapt it to another situation, be advised.

**Note 2:** There might be more things to change. As I am new to the Raspberry pi (I got mine 2 days ago), I may find other adjusts I left out and I will edit this answer again.

**Note 3:** My first attempt was to move `pi` user and `pi` group to another `UID` and `GID` (1001) and create a new user for me as `1000`. That didn't quite go as I planned and I needed to burn my SD card again after spending the whole day trying to figure out why the "configure you pi" program would not work anymore. But well, this way here is far easier anyway, so here you go: a new pi with just your username as UID 1000 (and all the good stuff in your home).

**Note 4:** Be advised, after doing that, the standard configuration tool stops working.

[image: Raspberry Pi Configuration Tool]

**footnote:** Thanks for the *stackexchange raspberrypi* community (as I'm new here also).

Comment: Small notes I found while following your steps: A fresh install on my raspian had `vi` but no `vim`. To get to the first `tty` I had to use `ctrl+alt+F1`.

Answer (score 3):

1. `sudo passwd root` 
   [enter new ridiculous root password. Remember it.]
2. Log/ssh into pi as root using ridiculous password.
3. `usermod -l newname -d /home/newname -m oldname`
4. `ls -al /home/` 
   [See that you've changed the user & home folder. Yay. Oh.. gotta change the group...]
5. `groupmod --new-name newname oldname`
6. `ls -al /home/`
   [See that user, group & home folder are changed. Yay!]
7. `exit` 
   (Now log in as newname. Yay!)
   But wait....
   Now you should reset root so others can't brute-force your ridiculous password.
8. `sudo passwd -l root`
   (Oh, and if you REALLY care... edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, setting "PermitRootLogin no", and restart that service.)

Then you'll have to change any additional changes in any scripts/setups that refer to 'pi'... JOY.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to just put this as a comment, but if booting into safe mode doesn't work, you can try doing this by creating a temporary account and operating from there. See the description here: https://askubuntu.com/a/34075/112715

Answer (score 0):

> DO NOT do this - you will likely end up with an unusable system.

I had the same problem here and I tried to kill the process one by one but I just cannnot kill them all. I found a much easier solution:
First make sure you have the password of root (su), then you can stop the auto login by 
`raspi-config`
Find the option of auto login and stop user "pi" auto log into desktop GUI without typing password.
After reboot, you would be asked to type in the password of "pi". Don't do it, intead press ctrl+alt+F2 to login as su then:
`sudo pkill -u pi`
Now all process that "pi" is using would be killed, you can change the name of user "pi" now.