# Messed up auto login

Tags: raspbian, login

So i tried to edit the `/etc/inittab` with `sudo nano /etc/inittab`:

I changed:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1
```

to:

```
1:2345:respawn:sbin/getty --autologin {USERNAME} --noclear 38400 tty1
```

Then I went ahead and changed it to:

```
1:2345:respawn:sbin/getty --autologin {pi} --noclear 38400 tty1
```

And was so stupid to forget to remove the brackets. now it's saying:

```
Authentication failure
INIT: Id "1" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes.
```

I know that i can fix it by simply removing the brackets but i can't enter the raspberry pi now because it locks immediately.

How can i go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there's [no way to boot into runlevel 1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3751/5538) on the pi without configuring it to do so first, which is not really an option at this point.

That line applies to runlevels 2, 3, 4, and 5; the original default is 2, and that's what you are getting.

The only thing you can do is take the card out and fix `inittab`.

---

If you can't access the second partition on Windows, you could try adding:

`init=/bin/bash`

To the end of `cmdline.txt` on the first (vfat) partition, which should remain *all one line*.  I can't promise this will work out, and you will certainly want to remove that afterward, but it may give you a command prompt.

Comment: how will i be able to access inittab by connecting it to my windows computer? from my previous experiences, i've never found anything that i need when simply connecting the card into my computer. like everything looks different.

Comment: Windows doesn't come with ext4 (the filesystem type) support.  There's some [solutions to that recommended here](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/), although I can't vouch for them.  The other options would be to either use [a linux "live CD"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD), or install it in a virtual machine such as VirtualBox on windows (which requires the .iso image for CD and is more work, but does not require you actually burn a disk).

Comment: Right now i was able to view the contents of the sd card and saw root.tar and opened it using winrar and i was able to locate the inittab. was able to open it using notepad. Is this gonna work?

Comment: I guess you might as well try...I've edited in another suggestion at the bottom, but it is a pretty sketchy one.

Comment: I tried it and nothing happened. Thanks for your effort though :) uhm will entering recovery mode work?

Comment: You mean using the jumper like in the linked Q&A?  I've never tried it but if it is as described there, yes it should work -- that won't use anything on the second partition but you should be able to access it.  Apparently [busybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) comes with a `vi` (simple editor) implementation, which would allow you to edit `inittab` -- but it is not easy to use...

Comment: If you have the option of burning the live CD, that's the surest bet.  They are usually slow and awkward, but have a full GUI desktop.

Comment: I tried the linked thread and the edit in cmdline.txt. nothing happened for both.

Comment: btw goldilocks, where should i add "init=/bin/bash" will it work by just simply adding it at the end of cmdline.txt?

Comment: I *think* so, but you might want to insert it right after the `root=...` parameter.

Comment: Alright i think i'm going somewhere here. i was finally able to open inittab using the raspberry pi itself but it says i have no permission to write it.

the console looks like this:

root@(none):/#

What i typed was:
root@(none):/# $sudo nano /etc/inittab

Comment: You don't have to use `sudo`, you're root.  If that's from busybox, it's the wrong `/etc/inittab`; you'll have to mount the 2nd partition first: `mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt` (then it should be in `/mnt/etc/inittab`).  If it isn't busybox, it's because the root fs is mounted read-only.  Try `mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2 /`.

Comment: Not using busybox or anything. Just my raspberry pi and i added in the "init=/bin/bash" comment after cmdline.txt so i'm gonna try "mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2 /"

Comment: Going to accept this since as an answer, since your replies was able to guide me to the things i need. I used the suggestion from the linked question. The one that simply uses "init/bin/sh" and the instructions that followed. I am now able to enter the raspberry pi :D